# How to access ext variable defined in build.gradle from settings.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have defined an ext variable in build.gradle:

```
ext {
    foo = "myVersion"
}
```

I would like to use this variable in settings.gradle, below options are not working:

```
plugins {
      id("myPlugin").version("${foo}")
      id("myPlugin").version(gradle.ext.foo)
      id("myPlugin").version(gradle.foo)
      id("myPlugin").version(foo)
      id("myPlugin").version(project.foo)
      id("myPlugin").version(rootProject.foo)
 }
```

How to do that properly? Based on documentation settings.gradle is loaded while initialisation and probably it won't work that way I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings file is applied before the build.gradle; so you can not use the variables that way. try using the gradle.properties

Comment: Answer I was looking for.

Comment: Is possible the other way then?